# How Can I Pivot a Table in Microsoft Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access, pivot, pivot-table

It used to be possible to pivot tables in older versions of Microsoft Access (Access 2010). The option to pivot tables seems now to have been removed.  Furthermore, the SQL PIVOT operator does not appear to be supported by MS Access.  So what are my options if I wish to pivot my data in an Access database?

Specifically, my problem is this: 
I have a '*Contacts*' table in my Access database which contains names, addresses, etc of my contacts, EXCEPT all phone numbers are stored in a separate '*PhoneNumber*' table.  This is because I want to give descriptions to each number.  So there are four columns in the PhoneNumbers table:

1. NumberID (Primary Key)
2. Contacts ID (Foreign Key)
3. Description (eg: 'Mobile', 'Home', 'Work')
4. PhoneNumber

The two tables are inner joined on contactID.

I wish to display all my records from the '*Contacts*' table together with the 'Description' field  from the '*PhoneNumbers*' table appended to this dataset.

The entries from the '*PhoneNumber*' field of the '*PhoneNumbers*' table, I wish to be presented as record entries inside the Description field.  This can be done using SQL `PIVOT` and using `MAX(PhoneNumber)` as the aggregating function -But, `PIVOT` does not appear to be supported in MS Access. Am I right?  If so, how can I achieve my aim?

Comment: In Microsoft Access, it's called a "Crosstab Query."

Answer (score 2):

MS removed interactive PivotTables and PivotCharts starting with Access 2013.

However, data pivot was and still is possible with CROSSTAB query. Use query designer and select CROSSTAB from the ribbon to build then switch to SQL View to see statement syntax. Or use the CROSSTAB query wizard. In either case, constructed SQL statement does use PIVOT clause.

Answer (score 1):

It's accurate pivot tables went away in the 2013 Access update. I've been looking for a workaround and found these HTML in Access options. Both have strong suits. Team-moeller is easy to set up and has run on every computer I have installed. But it has javascript files I've had to keep with the database. DEVelopers HUT PivotTable also charts it to bar graphs and other graph styles. But I've had a hard time getting it to work on every computer I've installed. Even using their workarounds. And fixing bugs in it has left me researching a lot, being an HTML novice.

team-moeller
https://github.com/team-moeller/better-access-pivottable

DEVelopers HUT
https://www.devhut.net/access-pivot-tables-and-pivot-charts/